# file_get_contents does not work in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, callback, file-get-contents

I have a function in my controller to fetch some data from a callback url. And the data will get updated in database automatically.

My callback url is **http://example.com/API/sendSMSCallback**

and this is my **sendSMSCallback** function in **API** controller

```
public function sendSMSCallback() {
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
    $data = array('value' => $json, 'date' => date('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
    $this->db->insert('test', $data);    // for testing

    $json = urldecode($json);        
    $obj = json_decode($json,TRUE);
    $reqID = $obj['req_id'];
    $status = $obj['status'];
    $mobile = $obj['msisdn'];

    $this->db->where('UniqueID', $reqID);
    $this->db->where('MobileNo', $mobile);
    $this->db->set('ResponseStatus', $status);
    $this->db->update('smslog_tbl');

    // for testing
    $this->load->helper('file');

    if ( ! write_file(base_url().'test.txt', $json)){
        echo 'Unable to write the file';
    }
    else{
        echo 'File written!';
    }
}
```

expected data in the form of json as follows

```
{"result":{"status":"success","req_id":"0d0dd0ce8-dadf-49fd-a49e-9845787e0507","msisdn":"91xxxxxxx, "}}
```

but nothing will get updated in **smslog_tbl** table and **test.txt** is empty. New row is inserted in **test** table, but **value** field is empty. Please help me to find out a solution. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE :** 
table structure : test

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`value` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
`date` datetime NOT NULL
```

Comment: test table structure pls

Comment: updated in my question

Comment: After `$json = file_get_contents('php://input');` try to do `var_dump($json);` and see any data is coming actually or not?

Answer (score 0):

First of all HTTP POST data is usually populated in $_POST, php://input will usually contain **PUT** data.

Also you need to allow

```
allow_url_fopen
```

in your php.ini config file. Some hosts disallow it for security

If you already done this then Check file_get_contents PHP Manual return value. If the value is FALSE then it could not read the file. If the value is NULL then the function itself is disabled.

To learn more what might gone wrong with the file_get_contents operation you must enable error reporting and the display of errors to actually read them.

```
# Enable Error Reporting and Display:
error_reporting(~0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: allow_url_fopen is On. I tested this url with one of my php file in local server. sometimes it is working, some times it will not

Comment: Are you sure that you are send the data with put or post?

Comment: I'm not sending data. it is a callback function. data comes from some other server and they said it is post parameter. so i just commented the code after `$this->db->insert('test', $data);`

Comment: i want to make sure how it comes, that 's why i'm directly inserted this data to my test table

Comment: So you can use curl instead